# Burn to specific sectors of flash memory

Tags: memory-management, filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel, bootloader

Is there any utility where I can exactly specify to which sector area the images are going to be burned ?

I need to burn an SD card according to a specific sector map,

e.g. bootloader should reside in 512K area from sector 57 to sector 1072 inclusively
kernel should reside in 4M area from sector 1073 to sector 9264 inclusively

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SECTOR_SIZE=<sector size in bytes>
FLASH_DEV=/dev/sd??
sudo dd if=boot.bin of=$FLASH_DEV bs=$SECTOR_SIZE count=$((1072-57)) seek=57
sudo dd if=kernel   of=$FLASH_DEV bs=$SECTOR_SIZE count=$((9264-1073)) seek=1073
```

Just `man 1 dd`, and you must determine name of your flash drive in /dev/sd* before.

Comment: thanks for reply, but, you know, my SD card is mounted as two ext4 partitions, /dev/mmcblk0p1 and /dev/mmcblk0p2. the former actually resides on sectors 34038-563517 and contains android system files. the latter resides on sectors 563518-2666309 and contains android data files. Other sectors of SD card are invisible. How can I access them ?

Comment: @mangusta is there the general /dev/mmcblk0 ? If so, just use it, if not, I'd try to investigate why only these two partitions are visible.

Comment: Ah, actually there is /dev/mmcblk0 : ) but I cannot mount it because it does not have an associated filesystem. should I necessarily mount it, in order to use dd?

Comment: @mangusta no, you must have /dev/mmcblk0 unmounted doing 'dd', otherwise you interfere with the kernel filesystem drivers which might cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @mangusta: Actually, you have to *not* mount it to use `dd` because dd is a block driver level transfer, and having block level transfer and file-system level at the same time on one medium is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dd utility and specify the sector offset with the 'seek' option